# Preventing duplicate guesses

Tags: java

I am working on code that will prevent the String from appending duplicate guesses, preventing 2 of the same letter from showing up. Currently the code is able to detect duplicate letter, however, only displays it after a second press.For example I press "q" and nothing happens. I press "q" again, and now the string updates with q. I want it to display q right after the first guess.

Code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keyChar = e.getKeyChar();
    String guessedLetters = buffer.toString();

        statusMsg.setText(model.guessNotification());

    if(guessedLetters.contains(Character.valueOf(keyChar).toString()))  {
        guessedLetters = buffer.toString();
    }
    else{
        buffer.append(keyChar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `Set<Character>` and `if(!add(c))`. This code is not an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's hard to provide more specific help. For example, what is `buffer`?

Comment: As mentioned to you before when you posted this same question as [Legend27](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7551076/legend27), please post a valid [mcve]. Let's see code that we can compile, run test and modify ourselves. @BoristheSpider: He's been asked to post a MCVE previously.

Comment: @noobcoder: which means that you are commenting before reading the [mcve] link. Please read the link first as no one is asking for all the code.

Comment: @noobcoder surely you can break this down into a `main` function, without a GUI, where the user types guesses to the commandline. I can see that as maybe 20 lines of code. In order for us to put the effort into working out your problem, _you_ need to put some effort in. In fact, isolating the issue into a MCVE will often help you figure it out by yourself.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: very well said

Comment: Why the new user name? Why not Legend27?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't re-assigning `guessedLetters` after you append a letter to the buffer.

(You also don't really need to re-assign `guessedLetters` in the `if` block, since the buffer hasn't changed since the first assignment.  But this is not the cause of your issue.)

(Also, as others have pointed out, a collection would be a better approach than a StringBuffer.  But you'd still have to convert the contents of the collection to a string for display, and you'd still have to remember to do that *after* adding an element to the collection.)

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you want to start with a `Set` of all the possible valid guesses the user could make. Then, after a guess, check that the set contains the guess (ie, that its valid) then remove that guess from the Set.

Comment: Or one could do the opposite - try and add guesses to the `Set`.